What is the name of the group of all circular slice rotations on the sphere?
Consider the following group that naturally acts on the $2$-sphere. An individual generator works by selecting a circle $c$ on the surface of the $2$-sphere, and then rotating $c$ in the plane containing $c$ (centered at $c$) by an angle $\theta$.
So in effect (if we are working on a unit sphere) we have that for every point $p$ on the sphere, for every possible radius up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for every possible angle from $0$ to $2\pi$ there exists a generator of this group. And we can chain uncountably infinitely many of these generators together to form individual elements of the group.
This is an EXTREMELY large group. It includes as subgroups ALL of the following:

The group of all rotations $\text{SO}(3)$
All sphere-based combination puzzle groups like the Rubiks cube and Pentaminx
The group of all area preserving diffeomorphisms sphere
The group of all area preserving homeomorphisms of the sphere

This group itself is a subgroup of the group of all area-preserving bijections from the sphere to itself.
I am curious about what the name of THIS group is. I want to read more about it. In particular I am also interested in knowing which lie groups does it contain? Does it for example contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\text{SO}(4)$?

This group is vast. From the way I solve Rubik's cubes, Gigaminxes and the like, I can immediately tell that it contains all the 3-cycles. That is, pick any three points $P,Q,R$ on the surface of the sphere, and the mapping that cyclically permutes
$$P\mapsto Q\mapsto R\mapsto P$$ and keeps all the other points fixed, is in there. It follows that all the even permutations of finite sets of points is also included.

The second sentence of your question does not even describe a map of the sphere, it only describes what it does to one circle. Is your map suppose to rotate all circles $C$ parallel to $c$ by some arbitrarily chosen angles $\theta_C$? Or is it supposed to rotate just one circle and keep all other points fixed? You get a "vast" group in the first case and a very small group in the 2nd case.

@MoisheKohan the action of an individual generator is to rotate just one circle and keep all other points fixed. But for every possible choice of circle and angle you have a generator of the group. Leading to a very large space of generators which themselves form words of uncountable length.

Hmm. A word of uncountable length does not really make sense. More precisely, I think that the rotations of the sphere are not included in your group. Each and every generator moves points on a set of measure zero. Therefore the same applies to every finite word of generators. And, guess what, those finite words form a group $G$. And that's your group because using your generators you won't get anything else! On the other hand, a rotation of, say, points with a latitude in an interval (w.r.t. some coordinate system) have a positive measure, and therefore is not in your group.

How would I include the following: to rotate the sphere say 90 degrees around a central axis. I could decompose the sphere into a number of circular slices (one for every real number from the non inclusive interval (-1,1) ) and rotate each slice 90 degrees. The result of all these rotations IS that the entire sphere has rotated 90 degrees about the axis.

So unless you change the description of the group, it won't contain $SO(3)$.

My instinct is to identify each of those slice rotations with a generator and the entire action of rotation then is a word of uncountable length. I need a language of “uncountably long words” to include rotations as you pointed out. Is that an ill defined concept?

To describe the group you want, I think you need to define the generators with a recipe like the following. Pick an axis $L$. It determines a slicing parametrized by a coordinate in the interval $[-1,1]$ (the point where the axis and the plane of a slice intersect). Pick any function $f:(-1,1)\to[0,2\pi)$. Define the permutation $R(L,f)$ that (simultaneously) rotates the slice with intercept $z\in(-1,1)$ by the angle $f(z)$. That way you can rotate a single slice by selecting an $f$ that vanishes everywhere except at a single point.

"A word" in this context is a composition of letters in the word, each standing for a function. How do you define a composition of infinitely many permutations? You can't, unless some special conditions apply. Here the special condition is that the permutations in "the infinite word" have disjoint supports. By support of a permutation $f$ I mean the set of points $x$ such that $f(x)\neq x$.

Yes that is I think a more accurate model of what I had in mind. So in this case the cardinality of the generators is the space of functions $(-1,1) \rightarrow [0,2\pi)$  (times a factor of cardinality of points on the sphere but I don’t think that affects anything). And then the words themselves can be of finite length.

I suggest you sit down with a piece of paper and try to formalize the notion of "uncountable length." My guess is that you will fail. Even countable words will present an analytical problem. Until then, "infinite length" is undefined and should be avoided. If you stick to the usual notion of a group generated by the given set of elements, the group you defined acts trivially on $L^p(S^2)$ for every $p$. In particular, it does not contain any of the groups you have mentioned, even $SO(3)$.

An idea that may or may not work: view words as function f from an ordered subset S of cardinality at most R to the generator set L satisfying the property that for all x in S, there exists a finite chain s_1<s_2<...s_k such that s_1 is the least element with f(s_1) acting on x, s_2 is the least element greater than s_1 with f(s_2) acting on f(s_1)x etc, and after f(s_k), no more elements act on f(s_k)...f(s_1)x. Note the restrictiveness of having "first" elements in addition to the finiteness. But I think this will encapsulate all the things you could possibly care about.
